# Xcode project keeps loading

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

[image: Whenever, I create a new react native project, my xcode keeps loading like this]

I am unable to run my react native project in xcode. It keeps loading as shown in the picture. I tried cleaning the build folder, removing derived data, deleting node modules and pods and reinstalling them but the issue persists. My project is associated with a git repo. I am successfully able to push my code and take pull. Normally, the current branch name shows up where it currently says "Loading...".
My xcode version in 14.2